# Find the minimum of $S = ax+by+cz$ for $x,y,z > 0$ given that $x+y+z = xyz$

Tags: contest-math, maxima-minima

Given $x,y,z \in \Bbb R^+$ satisfying
$$
x+y+z = xyz \tag{1},
$$
[image]

find the minimum value of the sum
$$
S=ax+by+cz,
$$
with $a,b,c \in \Bbb R^+$ are known parameters. For example,
$$
\color{red}{(a,b,c) = \left(\sqrt 7, \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2},\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{7}\right)}
$$

**The problem looks very simple. It suffices to find a plane $ax+by+cz = S$ which is tangent to the surface $x+y+z = xyz$.**

I know there exists a very clever (but unluckily not intuitive):

- From $(1)$, there exists a triangle $ABC$ satisfying:
  $x = \tan A,y =\tan B$ and $z = \tan C$.
- The sum $S$ becomes  $S = a \tan A+b \tan B + c\tan C $
- Applying the inequality: $\tan x \ge \tan y +(\tan y)'(x-y)$ for $(x,y) =  (A,p), (B,q)$ and $(C,r)$. These values $p,q,r$ are determined such that $a(\tan p)' = b(\tan q)' = c(\tan r)'$ and $p+q+r = \pi$
- The minimum of $S$ is equal to $a \tan p +b\tan q +c\tan r+...$

For $(a,b,c) = \left(\sqrt 7, \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2},\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{7}\right)$, $S$ reaches its minimum of $\color{red}{\frac{15}{2}}$ when $$
\color{red}{(x,y,z) =\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}, \frac{5}{\sqrt{7}},\sqrt{7}\right)}
$$

I believe there exists a more intuitive solution without using trigonometry.

---

Here is my attempt (not beautiful yet)

Let denote
$$P = ax+by+cz + \lambda(x+y+z - xyz)$$
From the first derivatives of $P$, we deduce
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{\lambda}+1 = yz \\
\frac{b}{\lambda}+1 = zx \\
\frac{c}{\lambda}+1 = xy\\  \tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$
From $(1),(2)$, we have a cubic equation of $\lambda$
$$\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}+\frac{1}{xy} =1 \implies 
\lambda^3   +\frac{a+b+c}{2}\lambda^2 -\frac{abc}{2} = 0 \tag{3}$$

**Remark**: At this step, I realize that the solution depends on the parameters $a,b,c$ (and then the equation $(3)$ can have 1 or $3$ roots). For $
\color{red}{(a,b,c) = \left(\sqrt 7, \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2},\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{7}\right)}
$, we have $\lambda = -\sqrt{7}/4$, $\frac{1}{4}(-\sqrt{7}-\sqrt{14})$ or $\frac{1}{4}(-\sqrt{7}+\sqrt{14})$.

The second derivarives of $P$ is a Hessian matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \lambda z&\lambda y\\
\lambda z &0 & \lambda x\\
\lambda y & \lambda x &0\\
\end{pmatrix} \tag{4}$$
The equation of 3 eigenvalues of $(4)$
$$p^3  - (x^2+y^2+z^2)p-2xyz =0 \tag{5}$$

**Remark**: It's very strange because the equation $(5)$ can't have $3$ positive roots nor $3$ negative roots, this means that the Hessian matrix can't be definite positive (negative). And all critical points of $(3)$ aren't extremum points of $S = ax+by+cz$.

---

Where is my error?

Comment: @CalvinLin  Ah, I only read the title.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me like your concern is that the substitution is not intuitive and seems magical/clever, as the rest is pretty direct. If so, I would say that on the contrary, that's a common trigonometric substitution to use given the condition $ x + y + z = xyz$.

Comment: @CalvinLin There are 2 tricks used here, the first one is the trigonometric substitution as you mentioned. The second one is the lemma $\tan x \ge \tan y +(\tan y)'(x-y)$ (which seems come from nowhere). 
I think I understand the proof. But I believe there exists another approach, perhaps longer but more natural (for instance, Lagrange's method,...) because the problem seems not too difficult (compared to other contest math problems). Use two tricks like these is too much.

Comment: What you're referring to as the "second trick is the lemma ..."  should be more generally referred to as: To max/min $ \sum a_i f(x_i) $ subject to $ \sum x_i  = X$, then at equality, $ a_i f' (x_i ^*) $ is a constant. This should be obvious, eg proof by contradiction that we can otherwise min/max the sum further.  (Note: Solving this condition need not be obvious for varying $a, b, c$.) $\quad$  Note that we just need $f$ is differentiable. We didn't need the convexity/tangent line condition $f(x) \geq f(y) + (x-y) f'(y)$, which was what you called the trick that came out of nowhere.

Comment: I don't think brute force is so bad here.  Use the constraint to eliminate $x$, say, then setting the partials to $0$ quickly resolves to $c(z^2+1)=b(y^2+1)$, and symmetry tells us these must also equal $a(x^2+1)$. which is not terrible.

Comment: @lulu I understand the proof which uses many interesting technique. But what I'm seeking here is another approach without using trigonometry. Besides, I try to use Lagrand's method and it seems to be a good method (I add my attempt in the question). The problem is the Hessian matrix is not definite positive (or negative) on critial points. I don't know where is my error.

Comment: @CalvinLin I added my attempt using the Lagrange's method which seems to me more natural. But perhaps I made a mistake somewhere (so, the Hessian matrix is not definite positive of negative) so I haven't yet the final solution.

Comment: There is in principle no contradiction. You only have to consider the Hessian matrix when restricted to the tangent space of the constraint. I don't have a good general formula for retrieving the signature of the resulting 2D problem so I don't write this as an answer. However, I did check that in the symmetric case $a=b=c$, $x=y=z$ the resulting problem is sign definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without using trigonometry.

**Note**: when I wrote the conclusion of this method, I found a second method which is simpler. I don't have time to write both two methods here.

Let denote
$$P = ax+by+cz + \lambda(x+y+z - xyz)$$
From the first derivatives of $P$, we deduce
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{\lambda}+1 = yz \\
\frac{b}{\lambda}+1 = zx \\
\frac{c}{\lambda}+1 = xy\\  \tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$
From $(1),(2)$, we have a cubic equation of $\lambda$
$$\frac{1}{yz}+\frac{1}{zx}+\frac{1}{xy} =1 \implies 
\lambda^3   +\frac{a+b+c}{2}\lambda^2 -\frac{abc}{2} = 0 \tag{3}$$

The equation $(3)$ has one positive root. We will prove that this root is unique in $\Bbb R$. Indeed, we know that $(3)$ can't have $3$ positive roots, then we suppose that there exists a negative root $\lambda'$, then
$$yz = 1-\frac{a}{\lambda'}<1 \implies x+y+z = xyz <x \implies y+z<0  \text{ : contradiction}$$

So, there is only one critical point $(x,y,z,\lambda)$ satisfying $(2)$ and $(3)$. ( $(x,y,z,\lambda)$ can be solved analytically).

The second derivarives of $P$ is a **bordered** Hessian matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -\frac{a}{\lambda} &-\frac{b}{\lambda} &-\frac{c}{\lambda} \\
-\frac{a}{\lambda}& 0 & -\lambda z & -\lambda y \\
-\frac{b}{\lambda} & -\lambda z &0 & -\lambda x\\
-\frac{c}{\lambda} & -\lambda y & -\lambda x &0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \tag{4}$$

**Remark**: In my attempt above, I made a mistake by not including the $4$-th dimension with the variable $\lambda$. And the bordered Hessian matrix is not necessary to be definite positive in the case of minimum with constraints.

The point $(x,y,z,\lambda)$ can be proved as a minimum point by checking the [sufficient condition for local extrema](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/uhan/sm286a/lessons/25.pdf) or [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Ehanifc/NotesOnHessians.pdf) . The idea is to calculate the determinant of $2$ [minors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) of the Hessian matrix. The $2$ determinants must be negative (same sign as $(-1)^1 = -1$).

- The first determinant is equal to $-2\frac{abz}{l}<0$
- The second determinant (the determinant of Hessian matrix) is equal to $(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)-2(abxy+bcyz+cazx)$. I haven't simplified this formula yet but it must be negative as well.

**Conclusion**: $P$ reaches its minimum equal to $$P_{\text{min}} = 2\frac{x_0y_0z_0}{\lambda}$$

with $(x_0,y_0,z_0,\lambda)$ is the solution of $(2)$ and $(3)$( $(x_0,y_0,z_0,\lambda)$ can be calculated analytically).

**Remark**: When I was writing the conclusion, I just found a second method which seems simpler than this method. Thanks to the second method, I could have easily the minimum value $P_{\text{min}} = 2\frac{x_0y_0z_0}{\lambda}$ (with the first method above, it's not easy to get $P_{\text{min}}$). I'll write the second method later.